# How do I append an object class to a list?

Tags: python, list, class

So I have the following function :

```
def find_by_name(self, name):
    fitting_list = [p for p in self.__persons if name.lower() in p.name.lower()]
    return fitting_list
```

And I get the following output when I want to print the list :

```
[<src.store.domain.person.Person object at 0x000001F88705B128>]
```

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: What do you expect instead?

Comment: I expect to print the list of objects with respect to the if condition. I have implemented __str__ method. Shouldn't that be enough?

Comment: That's what is does. It prints a list with one Person object. You see the default way Python prints objects.

Comment: BTW, that "persons" attribute should probably be called `.persons`, or maybe `._persons` if you want to indicate that it's a private name for use by your class's methods and that  code external to the class shouldn't touch it directly. Names that begin with double underscores (and end with at most a single underscore) invoke Python's [name mangling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables) machinery, and that should only be used when you _really_ need it. And if you have to ask "Do I need name mangling here?", you probably don't. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list` doesn't care that your class has a `__str__` method.

When you print an object, `print` calls `str` on the object to get a suitable string. The `str` function attempts to call the object's `__str__` method, but if it doesn't *have* one then it calls the object's `__repr__` method instead. And if their isn't a definition for `__repr__` in that object's class definition then you'll get the one inherited from the parent class, typically that will be the default  `__repr__` from the base `object` type.

`list` and the other built-in collections like `tuple`, `set` and `dict` don't have a `__str__` method, so when you try to convert them to strings (either explicitly using the `str` function, or implicitly via `print`) their `__repr__` method is called. And those `__repr__` methods in turn call `repr` on each item in the collection. So when you pass any of those collection objects to `print` you will always see the `__repr__` of the items. And explictly calling `str` on the collection will make no difference.

If you want to see the `__str__` representation of the items in a `list` or collection you will need to iterate over the collection, calling `str` explicitly on each item.

Here's a tiny code snippet (suitable for Python 2 & 3) that illustrates these points.

```
from __future__ import print_function

class Test(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Test str'
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Test repr'

a = [Test(), Test()]
print(id(a.__repr__), id(a.__str__))
print(a, str(a), repr(a))

for u in a:
    print(u, str(u), repr(u))
```

**output**

```
3075508812 3075508812
[Test repr, Test repr] [Test repr, Test repr] [Test repr, Test repr]
Test str Test str Test repr
Test str Test str Test repr
```

So if you want to be able to print a list of your objects as a single entity and have the object's strings be more human-friendly, you have a couple of choices:

1. Change the name of your `__str__` method to `__repr__`. This is the simplest way, and as I said earlier, the `__repr__` will be used if a `__str__` can't be found when the object gets passed to `str`.
2. Leave the existing `__str__` method alone and create a `__repr__` that's more human-friendly. However, it's suggested that the `__repr__` display useful info to a programmer who sees it, and if practical it's nice if the `__repr__` string can be copy & pasted into the interpreter or script to recreate the object.
3. Leave the existing `__str__` method alone and create a `__repr__` that calls `__str__`. While valid, this is a bit silly. A related strategy is to set `__repr__` as a class attribute that references `__str__`. See below for an example.

```
class Test(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Test str'
    __repr__ = __str__
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This made me understand the __str__ methoc a lot better than any other tutorial I've found.

Answer (score 3):

This is just the `__repr__` of the object. The `__repr__` is meant to be a machine readable representation of the object and you can change it by overiding it.